# ng-repeat scope issue: two level inheritance?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got an array of objects, these objects having properties.

I want to be able modify the properties of one of these objects thanks to a ng-repeat -> and that the changes I make are also done in the original array

I've tried to properly do format my array so that the inheritance is ok: when I change in the ng-repeat it changes in the $scope. But it doesn't go to the original array.

I don't know how I could change my data/arrays in order to make it work.

What should I do ? How can I transform my data ?

[here is a fiddle that shows all this](http://jsfiddle.net/Morgorth/xezbs8gn/6/)

ps: I've tried using the parent scope but as you can see in my example I don't even success in that :( anyway it's advised to avoid it if possible

and here's the JS code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
    //source array
    var origine = [
        {id:"1",name:"elem1"},
        {id:"2",name:"elem2"},
        {id:"3",name:"elem3"} ];

    //what I am doing now
    $scope.element = origine[1];

    //i'd like to transform the array so that I have inheritance and I can avoid using parent scope

    var reference = [];
    var i =0;
    for (var key in origine[2]) {
      if (origine[1].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          reference[i] = {prop:origine[2][key]};
          i++;
      }
    }

    $scope.element2 = reference;

    $scope.element3 = origine[0];


    $scope.check = function()
    {    
        //to check if the source array is modified
         console.log(origine);
    }

});
```

and here HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        --------------- BASIC example -----------------
        <br/> Repeat scope
        <div ng-repeat="property in element">
           <input ng-model="property"/>
        </div>     

       <br/>"Parent"
        <input ng-model="element.name"/>
        <br/><input type="button" ng-click="check()" value="check origine"/>

        <br/><br/>--------------- Trying inheritance  -----------------
        <br/> Repeat scope
        <div ng-repeat="property in element2">
           <input ng-model="property.prop"/>
        </div>     

       <br/> "Parent"
        <input ng-model="element2[1].prop"/>       
        <br/><input type="button" ng-click="check()" value="check origine"/>

        <br/><br/>--------------- Trying parent scope -----------------
        <br/> Repeat scope
        <div ng-repeat="property in element3">
           <input ng-model="$parent.property"/>
        </div>     

       <br/> "Parent"
        <input ng-model="element3.name"/>       
        <br/><input type="button" ng-click="check()" value="check origine"/>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because the variable is being assigned by reference.

Try assigning the array directly to the scope and manipulate that array, or create a scope method to push, splice, update that private array

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly you can refer to property by key to get it updated:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, property) in element">
    <input ng-model="element[key]"/>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xezbs8gn/7/

Comment: Now when you type inside ng-repeat input value changes inside "Parent" too. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: that was the case in my original example. What I want is the value to be modified in the original array (origine) too.